# Connecting two routers with separate internet connections(WAN)

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, bridge

[image]

Please refer to the figure above.

I need machine Y (my personal computer) to be able to connect to machine X (a Raspberry Pi server). I have full control over Router A and B and both routers have Wifi and bridging capability.

The only limitation is that I can't have other machines in A's LAN accessing the internet via router B and vice versa. So I don't think that a network bridge will work. I also don't want to connect X and Y via the internet because that would effect performance and cost bandwidth.

#### Is there a way I can connect router A and B so that X can talk to Y without effecting other nodes in both networks?

Comment: This requires a network switch.

Comment: Connect routers A and B; configure a route for subnet B via B on A and for subnet A via A on B; add packet filtering rules (`iptables`, or whatever packet filtering tool you have on the routers) to block any traffic not between the nodes X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how routing (at layers 2 and 3) works

Have a read:

- https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples
- https://www.cloudibee.com/static-route-linux/

The LAN-side address space for networks X and Y should be distinct.

Assuming the following:

- Device X is 192.168.1.111 (static IP)
- Network for X is 192.168.1.0/24
- Router A is 192.168.1.1
- Device Y is 192.168.2.222 (static IP)
- Network for Y is 192.168.2.0/24
- Router B is 192.168.2.1

You need to:

- Bridge routers A and B (connect a cable on the LAN side of each device)
- On router A, add a static route for station Y through router B

  ```
  # ip route add 192.168.2.222/32 via 192.168.2.1
  ```

  On router B, add a static route for station X through router A

  ```
  # ip route add 192.168.1.111/32 via 192.168.1.1
  ```

Comment: Newbie here, when you say "Router A is 192.168.1.1", who assigned it this IP address? It only has t his IP address in its own subnet right? The other router can't connect to 192.168.1.1, right?

Comment: Everything under "Assuming" means it must be done before you proceed.  Router A being 192.168.1.1 (and similar for Router B) must be configured by the network engineer (probably you).    ***It only has this IP address in its own subnet right?*** No.  It must be able to talk to the clients in its network (192.168.1.0/24).  ***The other router can't connect to 192.168.1.1, right?***  Correct.  Router B doesn't have a route for 192.168.1.1 so it _doesn't know how_ to reach it therefore it can't.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way I can connect router A and B so that X can talk to Y without effecting other nodes in both networks?

If you really only care about getting Y to talk to X with your requirement that Y does not allow Internet access to hosts in Y's LAN, you don't really need to involve the router at all.

- Install a 2nd NIC on Y.
- Connect 2nd NIC on Y to Router A's LAN - this can be one of the LAN ports on router A, for example.

That's it.

- Y will be able to talk to X, and even get an IP from the DHCP server on X's LAN.
- Y will not forward traffic from X's LAN to the internet unless you enable Internet Connection Sharing (on Windows) or ip forwarding (on Linux) or the similar equivalent on Mac (not sure what that is).
- You may look into putting a firewall configuration on Y that enforces this.

> is there a way I can connect router A and B so that X can talk to Y without effecting other nodes in both networks?

Yes, but your router needs more than just a LAN and WAN interface.  You need a third interface on both routers and static routing configured between them, and a firewall/forwarding configuration that supports what you want with Internet access.

Assuming you are working with normal home router type hardware:

On most 4-port home routers, the 4 LAN ports are a switch - conceptually all just one LAN interface.

If you can install OpenWRT/LEDE on these routers, or the router has OpenWRT/LEDE-based firmware (like Asus), and the chipset in the routers is a Broadcom chipset, you may be able to turn one port from the LAN interface into its own independent "third" interface.  The 5 ports in such hardware  are technically a switch and a utility can be used to "VLAN off" internally individual ports so they appear to the embedded Linux as unique separate interfaces.

OpenWRT/LEDE provides a web-based interface for this - you can change the switch port assignments, assign static routing, firewalling, etc.  This is the easiest route I've found.

DD-WRT and AsusWRT don't - you have to log into a shell on the built-in Linux OS in the router and issue commands - `robocfg` being the weirdly named command that configures the hardware.  Experimentation is needed because the port numbers vary by platform.  Also Broadcom doesn't provide full hardware details to Linux kernel developers so `robocfg` may not work on all Broadcom hardware revisions and such.

Comment: Who thought this was a good solution?! Buying a new NIC instead of just buying an Ethernet cable. Drilling holes and so on to connect a computer to a router that is at tens/hundreds meters away (yes router A and B can be in two different buildings).

Comment: You fantasised about different buildings and drilling walls. Nothing in OP question indicates that. Why don't you get all upset of possibility of on the routers in question to be a marshmallow? Who on earth would stick an ethernet cable into a perfectly made fresh marshmallow.